# Ghostscript - don't show objects with overprint set

Tags: ghostscript

I'm trying to convert preview pdfs uploaded by converting them to jpeg. Please can someone tell me how I can preview overprint? i.e. if a white object is set to overprint over a coloured background it shouldn't be shown - we only see the background.

```
/c 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin64c.exe' -o image%04d.jpg -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=60 -r150 -dSimulateOverprint=false -dUseCropBox uploaded.pdf
```

Also how can I output/list the created files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overprint is only defined for CMYK inks, so you need to run to a device which support CMYK output. If you go to gray or RGB then the CMYK values are converted to RGB and will no longer overprint.

Try the tiff32nc device. Or jpegcmyk if you really want to use jpeg.